# Prove there exists $a$ such that $a^\frac{n-1}{2} \neq (\frac{a}{n}) (\text{mod } n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, jacobi-symbol

I want to prove the following proposition:

> Let $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are odd primes; Prove there exists a number $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^x$ such that $a^\frac{n-1}{2} \neq (\frac{a}{n}) (\text{mod } n)$

I've tried assuming by contradiction that for each $a$ the two sides are equal, but it doesn't seem to help...

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume, at first, that the primes are distinct.

Choose a non-square $\pmod p$, call it $n$.  We can find an integer $N$ such that $$N\equiv n\pmod p\quad \& \quad N\equiv 1 \pmod q$$

Clearly we have $$\left( \frac Nn\right)=-1$$

Now consider $$N^{(n-1)/2}\pmod n$$ Suppose (counter to hypothesis) that this was $-1\pmod n$.  Then we'd have $$N^{(n-1)/2}\equiv -1 \pmod n\implies N^{(n-1)/2}\equiv -1 \pmod q$$

But $N\equiv 1 \pmod q$ so the last congruence is absurd, hence we have a contradiction.

Note: We didn't need to make $N\equiv 1 \pmod q$, any square would have done as well.  Therefore, this argument shows that there are quite a few examples $\pmod {pq}$.  Indeed, half of the non-zero residues must be of the desired form (congruent to a square modulo one of the primes and a non-square modulo the other).  Thus, at least half of the non-zero residues must be of the form you seek.

Finally:  If $n=p^2$ then consider $N=p+1$.  We remark that  $$N^{(p^2-1)/2}\equiv \pm 1 \pmod n \implies N^{(p^2-1)}\equiv  1 \pmod n$$ Thus we get $$(1+p)^{p^2-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}\implies 1+(p^2-1)p\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}\implies -p\equiv 0\pmod {p^2}$$ which is absurd.

Comment: Very nice! I was about to post a proof, but yours is much nicer.